# generate temporary file in shell script

Tags: shell, csv

I am writing shell script in which i am fetching data from log file and creating a output file in csv(for example output.csv) which works fine for me. Now my requirement is while fetching data from log file script should write data in temporary file(for example sample.temp) and after completion move it to output.csv and then delete the generated temporary file. Please help to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The `mktemp` command will give you temporary file names to work with that look like `/tmp/tmp.B5oqPG0jCu`.  You can override the target directory with the `--tmpdir` argument (such as `mktemp --tmpdir=/home/user/theirtmp`) or append a suffix (`mktemp --suffix=.csv`).

It's only a name, so you can do something like this.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
tmpfile=$(mktemp --suffix=.dat)
head -1 /dev/random > $tmpfile # just filling the file with garbage, here
mv $tmpfile output.csv
```

Moving it already gets the original, but you can also (obviously) dump the file *contents* into another file (`cat $tmpfile >> output.csv`) and then delete it (`rm $tmpfile`), instead.